# Using Jquery to filter div in bootstrap framework

Tags: jquery, filter, twitter-bootstrap-3

Edited for more detail:

I am designing a website using the twitter bootstrap framework.
I want to filter out a couple div using jquery, so I did a research online and here is what I got.

First comes the Filter button list (inside a div) with some css styling the ul list.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8">
<ul id="filterOptions">
  <li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="UX">UX</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="UI">UI</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="Graphic">Graphic</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="Design">Design</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then several nested div

```
  <div class="row">
  <div id="ourHolder">   
  <div class="col-lg-6 UX">
  <img src="img/DTB1.png">
   </div>


  <div class="col-lg-6 UI">
  <img src="img/EDB1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 Graphic">
  <img src="img/STB1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 Design">
  <img src="img/MOV1.png">
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Then the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#filterOptions li a').click(function() {

var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');

$('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');


$(this).parent().addClass('active');

if(ourClass == 'all') {

  $('#ourHolder').children('div.item').show();
}
else {

  $('#ourHolder').children('div:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide();

  $('#ourHolder').children('div.' + ourClass).show();

}

return false;

  });

});
```

Somehow none of these buttons are working for me, if anyone can give me a hand here to tell me what am I missing, it will be very helpful!

Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming the nested divs are correctly placed under a div called #ourHolder?

Comment: Yes, there is one div with the id #ourHolder wrapping all the nested div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code into a fiddle and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xaNVL/

The problem might be that your nested divs aren't the immediate children of #ourHolder. In that case you can try to use `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

```
<div id="ourHolder">
<div class="col-lg-6 UX">
    <img src="img/DTB1.png">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 UI">
    <img src="img/EDB1.png">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 Graphic">
    <img src="img/STB1.png">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 Design">
    <img src="img/MOV1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Weird! I found that I actually have another <div class="row" outside the ourHolder div, would that be the problem? I edited the original code

Comment: @SamuelShen Don't think the extra `.row` would be the problem because your selector already starts from `#ourHolder`. Are you getting any errors on your page when you click a link? Try outputting some variables to your console.

Comment: I just checked the console and see this - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' - I think I was using prototype.js and caused the two of them righting over using $ ......That's exactly the issue